# Docker GitHub actions with parameters on build step

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am looking if it's possible to build a docker container from a Dockerfile with args.

The purpose is to have a dynamic "FROM" in the Dockerfile.
So in the `FROM circleci/android:api-28`, the `api-28` to be a parameter

So for a constant given Dockerfile:

```
FROM circleci/android:api-28    
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh    
RUN sudo chmod +x entrypoint.sh    

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Github actions build the following image:

```
Build Diolor/Android-build-action@master2m 8s
Successfully tagged 2e4e3a:89928963f88542989ff9d771e524d2d6
Build container for action use: '/home/runner/work/_actions/Diolor/Android-build-action/master/Dockerfile'.
/usr/bin/docker build -t 2e4e3a:89928963f88542989ff9d771e524d2d6 "/home/runner/work/_actions/Diolor/Android-build-action/master"
```

Does Github Actions allow environment params or arg params on that build step?

The goal is the Action consumer to use a different docker container tag, if he desires.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment to ask questions due to my reputation but I'll try to answer.

I don't know your workflow but if I understand well, you can use args keyword and also entrypoint like that :

```
steps:
  - name: It does something 
    uses: circleci/android:api-28
    with:
      entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
      args: |
         COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
         RUN sudo chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

I really don't know if it will work like that, but maybe [this documentation can help you](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepswithargs).

Comment: Ahh maybe I did not write it well enough. The workflow uses an action. And that action is creating a docker container based on `circleci/android:api-28`. But I question if it can also build another api level

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment earlier, you can in another job in the same workflow. But there would have no link between the two jobs.